# Linq returning incorrect values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ statement which is returning incorrect data.

I need to select each product which is active, and have the prices displayed according to the usertype logged in.  (Each user type has a different price)

I currently have five acive items in the database, but only two are showing.

```
public IQueryable GetProductsForListViewByUserType(Guid userTypeID)
{
    return
        (from p in this.Entities.Product
        join b in this.Entities.Brand on p.BrandID equals b.ID
        join ut in this.Entities.UserTypePrice on p.ID equals ut.ProductID
        where p.Active == true && ut.UserTypeID == userTypeID
        select new
        {
            p.ID,
            p.Name,
            Price = ut.Price,
            p.Description,
            BrandName = b.Name,
            p.Colour,
            p.ImageURL
        });
}
```

Not all active items are being returned from the query.

Personally, the statement syntax seems to be fine.  But I would like to know other people's views about this.

I debugged the statement, that's why I know that the problem is within the statement itself.

Comment: Could you post the 5 items that you think should be showing in this query?

Comment: Do all five of them have brands and applicable usertype prices?

Comment: Query looks good, can you paste some sample data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is that the problem is with `userTypeID`, if it's missing from `Entities.UserTypePrice` the product won't be returned.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that out.  Thank you.